# SAS merging 2 CSV files using a third that converts one ID to another

Tags: csv, merge, sas

New to StackOverflow. Thanks so much for entertaining this question. Been at it all day trying to merge files in SAS.

I have three relevant files: 
(1) a CSV file "all.csv" with relevant data that needs to be merged with CSV file (2) "ff.csv". Suppose all.csv had a 6 digit identifier called id and ff.csv had a 6 digit identifier called ID1. Csv file number (3) contains a table that matches "id" to "ID1."

ID1 and "id" have 1:1 matching but the ones from ff/ID1 has more people than I need (I need everyone from all.csv but only the ones from ff.csv that "match" all.csv).

What is the best way to do this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Please post what you've tried. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins Based on this, you probably want a left join x 2.

Comment: StackOverflow requires that you post an attempt at your problem, rather than just a problem statement with a request for code.

Comment: I was trying to add the code but was having issues with the formatting (code quoting wasn't formatting into columns properly). Regardless, both Reeza and Salva got me there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that your third CSV file has two columns called id and ID1, I would do the following.
1. Convert all three files into SAS datasets.
2. Merge all three tables using PROC SQL.  According to your conditions, you need two left joins.

```
proc sql;
    select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
    from one as t1 
      left join three as t3
        on t1.id = t3.id 
      left join two as t2
        on t2.id1 = t3.id1
quit;
```

EDIT:

If you run this code, you will see the query works.

```
data one;
  length id 3. country $ 32;
  input id country;
  infile datalines dsd;
  datalines;  
1,CANADA
2,FRANCE
3,GERMANY
4,JAPAN
;
run;
data two;
  length id1 3. city $ 32;
  input id1 city;
  infile datalines dsd;
  datalines;
1,BERLIN
2,TOKYO
3,TORONTO
4,MEXICO
5,PARIS
6,MADRID
;
run;  
data three;
    length id 3. id1 3.;
  input id id1;
  infile datalines dsd;
  datalines;
1,3
2,5
3,1
4,2
;
run;  
proc sql;
  select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
    from one as t1 
      left join three as t3
        on t1.id = t3.id 
      left join two as t2
        on t2.id1 = t3.id1
  ;
quit;
```